# Django 1.8.6 how to upload image optionally

Tags: django

eh.. I don't know how to describe the question, which is why I could not find a right solution. I'll explain it as specifically as I can. 
I want to upload the image in an article only if I want to, but if I don't, the form remind me this"This field is required". How do I fix it?
Here are my related codes:

```
def post(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NoteText(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        data1 = form.cleaned_data
        # data2 = subject.cleaned_data
        title = data1['title']
        content = data1['content']
        category = data1['category']
        subject_name = data1['subject_name']
        photo = data1['photo']

        # subject_name = data2['subject']
        if not Note.objects.all().filter(title=title):
            note = Note(title=title,
                        content=content,
                        created=timezone.now(),
                        category=category,
                        subject_name=subject_name,
                        photo = photo)
            note.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/notebook/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('The title has been used')
else:
    form=NoteText()
    # subject=SubjectText()
return render(request,'notebook/post.html',{'form':form})
```

in HTML:post.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'post' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    {{ form.as_table }}

</table>

{% csrf_token %}
```

detail.html:

```
<div>
    {% if note.photo %}
        <img src="{{ note.photo.url }}" />
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

If I have to upload, how do I upload an initial image? 
And if I want to upload multiple image, Does the FilerImageField help?

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with a `Form` then you can set the [`required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#required) property of the field to false

> By default, each Field class assumes the value is required

If you're working with a `ModelForm`, then you can set the [`blank`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#blank) property of the model field to True

> If a field has blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value.